# results from different functions to make a receipt

Tags: python, function, receipt

I need help with printing a receipt for my program, so basically, the user will enter their personal details into the program and I tried to make the validation perfect by using the functions below but the problem is that when I use those functions for validtion, I don't know how to get the correct info from function to my receipt. I don't know how to put all that results from different functions into one receipt like how I formated at the bottom. when the receipt is printed it says that (date: None)(email: None) (phone: None) but the actual input in the receipt I have tried in many different ways is not working.

```
def date():
    inputDate = input("Enter the booking date in format 'dd/mm/yy' : ")

    day, month, year = inputDate.split('/')

    isValidDate = True
    try:
        datetime.datetime(int(year), int(month), int(day))
    except ValueError:
        isValidDate = False

    if(isValidDate):
        print("Input date is valid ..")
    else:
        print("Input date is not valid..")
        date()


def validateEmail(email):
    return re.match(r'[\w-]{1,20}@\w{2,20}\.\w{2,3}$', email)



def checkemail():
    email = console.input('[bright_white]Please enter your email address: [/]')
    valid = validateEmail(email)
    if valid:
        print(email, 'is valid')
    else:
        print("invalid email format", email)
        checkemail()

def phone():
    phoneno = console.input('[bright_white]Please enter your phone number :[/] ')
    patter = r"^(1|8|9)[0-9]{7}"

    if re.match(patter, phoneno) and len(phoneno) == 8:
        print("Valid")
    else:
        print("Invalid")
        phone()


def booking_form():

    bookings = []


    FirstName = input('Please enter your first name: ')
    LastName = input('Please enter your last name: ')
    Email = checkemail()
    ContactNumber = phone()
    Date = date()
    Time = input('Enter time in 00:00 AM/PM format:')
    Gym = input("Please Enter the Name of the Gym Again to Ensure that to be the Correct one:  ")
    Commentsrequest = input('Comments/Additional Request: ')


    bookings.append(FirstName)
    bookings.append(LastName)
    bookings.append(Email)
    bookings.append(ContactNumber)
    bookings.append(Date)
    bookings.append(Time)
    bookings.append(Gym)
    bookings.append(Commentsrequest)


    with open("booking.csv", 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow(bookings)


    print(" Date:", date())
    print(" Time:", Time)
    print(" First Name:", FirstName)
    print(" Last Name:", LastName)
    print(" Email:", validateEmail(email))
    print(" Phone Number:", ContactNumber)
    print(" Chosen Location [Area/Gym]:", Gym)
    print(" Additional Notes/Requests:", Commentsrequest)
    print("**********************************************************************", )
    print("|         Thank You for Using the Volleyball Booking System          |", )
    print("|            You have Successfully Booked a Court/Gym                |", )
    print("|             Please Screenshot this Receipt to Keep                 |", )
    print("|                      as Proof of Booking                           |", )
    print("|          Have a Good Day, We will see you on the Court!!           |", )
    print(
        "                          ★★★★★★★★★★★★                              ")
    print("**********************************************************************", )
    exit()
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question, but you might want to make a class called Receipt with the different attributes like first_name, last_name etc. and use something like [pydantic][1] for validation. Then you can have a print_receipt method to output your desired format.
[1]: https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io

Comment: yeah, but how do I do it tho cause I never even heard of the stuff you're talking about.

Comment: Your functions don't [return](https://realpython.com/python-return-statement/) anything. Make sure to return the date, email, etc. Otherwise nothing can be printed in `booking_form()`.

Comment: can you show me an example of it please

Answer (score 0):

Your functions don't return anything, so you can't print the result because it will always be `None`. also, why did you called the functions again when you tried to print? you don't need to do that, you already saved them before.
This is the fixed code:

```
import re
import datetime
import csv

def date():

    inputDate = input("Enter the booking date in format 'dd/mm/yy' : ")
    day, month, year = inputDate.split('/')
    isValidDate = True
    try:
        datetime.datetime(int(year), int(month), int(day))
    except ValueError:
        isValidDate = False

    if(isValidDate):
        return datetime.datetime(int(year), int(month), int(day))
    else:
        print("Input date is not valid..")
        date()


def validateEmail(email):
    return re.match(r'[\w-]{1,20}@\w{2,20}\.\w{2,3}$', email)



def checkemail():
    email = input('[bright_white]Please enter your email address: [/]')
    valid = validateEmail(email)
    if valid:
        return email
    else:
        print("invalid email format", email)
        checkemail()

def phone():
    phoneno = input('[bright_white]Please enter your phone number :[/] ')
    patter = r"^(1|8|9)[0-9]{7}"

    if re.match(patter, phoneno) and len(phoneno) == 8:
        return phoneno
    else:
        print("Invalid")
        phone()


def booking_form():

    bookings = []


    FirstName = input('Please enter your first name: ')
    LastName = input('Please enter your last name: ')
    Email = checkemail()
    ContactNumber = phone()
    Date = date()
    Time = input('Enter time in 00:00 AM/PM format:')
    Gym = input("Please Enter the Name of the Gym Again to Ensure that to be the Correct one:  ")
    Commentsrequest = input('Comments/Additional Request: ')


    bookings.append(FirstName)
    bookings.append(LastName)
    bookings.append(Email)
    bookings.append(ContactNumber)
    bookings.append(Date)
    bookings.append(Time)
    bookings.append(Gym)
    bookings.append(Commentsrequest)


    with open("booking.csv", 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow(bookings)


    print(" Date:", Date)
    print(" Time:", Time)
    print(" First Name:", FirstName)
    print(" Last Name:", LastName)
    print(" Email:", Email)
    print(" Phone Number:", ContactNumber)
    print(" Chosen Location [Area/Gym]:", Gym)
    print(" Additional Notes/Requests:", Commentsrequest)
    print("**********************************************************************", )
    print("|         Thank You for Using the Volleyball Booking System          |", )
    print("|            You have Successfully Booked a Court/Gym                |", )
    print("|             Please Screenshot this Receipt to Keep                 |", )
    print("|                      as Proof of Booking                           |", )
    print("|          Have a Good Day, We will see you on the Court!!           |", )
    print(
        "                          ★★★★★★★★★★★★                              ")
    print("**********************************************************************", )
    exit()


booking_form()
```

Summary of the changes I have done:
In the `date()` function, instead of printing that the date is valid, I have **returned**  the valid email, and keep looping on the function is the date isn't valid.

I did the same with `checkemail()`, I have **returned** the valid email, and if not valid, ask the user for a valid one.

Same with `phone()` function.

At the printing statements at the end of the file, I just used the variable `Date` that you created earlier instead of calling `date()` function and ask the user for another date again. Same with the email.

Now it works fine (Just know that you never check the time and input can be invalid).