# How do I link the validation function to a receipt

Tags: python, function, validation, receipt

I need help with printing a receipt for my program, so basically, the user will enter their personal details into the program and I tried to make the validation perfect by using the functions below but the problem is that when I use those functions for validation, I don't know how to get the correct info from function to my receipt.

```
def date():
    inputDate = input("Enter the booking date in format 'dd/mm/yy' : ")

    day, month, year = inputDate.split('/')

    isValidDate = True
    try:
        datetime.datetime(int(year), int(month), int(day))
    except ValueError:
        isValidDate = False

    if(isValidDate):
        print("Input date is valid ..")
    else:
        print("Input date is not valid..")
        date()


def validateEmail(email):
    return re.match(r'[\w-]{1,20}@\w{2,20}\.\w{2,3}$', email)



def checkemail():
    email = console.input('[bright_white]Please enter your email address: [/]')
    valid = validateEmail(email)
    if valid:
        print(email, 'is valid')
    else:
        print("invalid email format", email)
        checkemail()

def phone():
    phoneno = console.input('[bright_white]Please enter your phone number :[/] ')
    patter = r"^(1|8|9)[0-9]{7}"

    if re.match(patter, phoneno) and len(phoneno) == 8:
        print("Valid")
    else:
        print("Invalid")
        phone()


def booking_form():

    bookings = []


    FirstName = input('Please enter your first name: ')
    LastName = input('Please enter your last name: ')
    Email = checkemail()
    ContactNumber = phone()
    Date = date()
    Time = input('Enter time in 00:00 AM/PM format:')
    Gym = input("Please Enter the Name of the Gym Again to Ensure that to be the Correct one:  ")
    Commentsrequest = input('Comments/Additional Request: ')


    bookings.append(FirstName)
    bookings.append(LastName)
    bookings.append(Email)
    bookings.append(ContactNumber)
    bookings.append(Date)
    bookings.append(Time)
    bookings.append(Gym)
    bookings.append(Commentsrequest)


    with open("booking.csv", 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow(bookings)


    print(" Date:", date())
    print(" Time:", Time)
    print(" First Name:", FirstName)
    print(" Last Name:", LastName)
    print(" Email:", validateEmail(email))
    print(" Phone Number:", ContactNumber)
    print(" Chosen Location [Area/Gym]:", Gym)
    print(" Additional Notes/Requests:", Commentsrequest)
    print("**********************************************************************", )
    print("|         Thank You for Using the Volleyball Booking System          |", )
    print("|            You have Successfully Booked a Court/Gym                |", )
    print("|             Please Screenshot this Receipt to Keep                 |", )
    print("|                      as Proof of Booking                           |", )
    print("|          Have a Good Day, We will see you on the Court!!           |", )
    print(
        "                          ★★★★★★★★★★★★                              ")
    print("**********************************************************************", )
    exit()
```

Comment: What is the exact problem you are having? Because in your provided code there are multiple problems!

Comment: Don't ask questions twice because you can't wait for people to answer you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68884515/results-from-different-functions-to-make-a-receipt I just answered your question there, and what you doing is called spam.

Comment: @Eladtopaz Martin had probably marked this question as duplicate, after reading your comment.

Comment: Yep, that was an automated comment by SO. I just tagged it, so the duplicate gets removed by someone with more rights and authority. Thank you for pointing it out.